# Is there a limit to how many SpatRasters can be handled by terra::compareGeom() in R?

Tags: r, terra

I want to ensure that my 8 SpatRasters have the same extent so that I can combine them as layers in the same SpatRaster. When I use `compareGeom()` with more than 3 SpatRasters, I get this error: `Error: could not find valid method`. Different combinations work as long as there are no more than 3 at a time.

Is there a limit of 3?

```
# check if extents are equal:
terra::compareGeom(dem20,
            dem20_Rcls100,
            vi_leafOff,
            vi_leafOn,
            vi_mcDif,
            tpi,
            tpi_Rcls,
            coastDis,
            lyrs = FALSE, crs = FALSE, warncrs = TRUE,
            ext = TRUE, rowcol = FALSE, res = FALSE, 
            stopOnError = FALSE, messages = TRUE)

Error: could not find valid method
```

Edit: Actually, the code as written isn't identifying mismatched extents correctly. So there's more I don't understand and I may not have the arguments set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug. I just fixed it and now I can do:

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.20
r1 <- rast()
r2 <- rast()
r3 <- rast()
compareGeom(r1, r2, r3, r1, r2, r3, r1, r2, r3)
#[1] TRUE
```

You can see for yourself with the [development version](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) of terra.

Comment: thanks, I was able to install the development version with devtools and no longer get the error. But if the resolution changes (e.g., res(r1) <- c(2,2)) I get FALSE even when I have the option res = FALSE. I can put this over in github if that's better.